# NFC Tag Reading

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

I got an application that reads and writes nfc tags with ndef data format. This all seems to be ok. But whenever i try to get closer a tag to my phone, it produces a new activity. I only want to obtain data on the tag without opening new intent. So i can make my app decide whether the tag has been tapped two times in a row.

The code that i handle coming tags:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static Context myContext;
private Button myButton;
private int currentID, currentBalance;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { // Firstly Created when
                                                        // a tag tapped to
                                                        // the phone
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    currentID = 0;
    currentBalance = 0;


    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // Tag write
                                                                // function
                                                                // places
                                                               // here

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nfcWrite.class);
            i.putExtra("id",currentID);
            i.putExtra("balance",currentBalance);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();


    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        NdefRecord myRecord = ((NdefMessage) rawMsgs[0]).getRecords()[0];
        String nfcData = new String(myRecord.getPayload());
        String[] splitData = nfcData.split("-");
        currentID = Integer.parseInt(splitData[0]);
        currentBalance = Integer.parseInt(splitData[1]);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), nfcData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to the `<activity>` element for `MainActivity`. Note that if the activity is already running, `onNewIntent()` will be called, instead of `onCreate()`, to deliver the NDEF `Intent` to you. Hence, you will need to handle the NDEF `Intent` in both `onCreate()` (if the activity was not already running) and `onNewIntent()` (if the activity was already running).

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/NFC/WebBeam) illustrates the technique.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting the launch-mode of the activity that receives the NFC intents to "singleTask" (see CommonsWare's answer), the preferred way for NFC applications to receive NFC-related intents while the app is in foreground is the [foreground dispatch system](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch) (or alternatively the [reader mode API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#enableReaderMode%28android.app.Activity,%20android.nfc.NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29) when using only Android 4.4).

In order to use the foreground dispatch, you would create a pending intent like this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    this,
    0,
    new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),
    0);
```

Then, in your activity's `onResume()` method, you would enable the foreground dispatch like this:

```
NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null, null);
```

You will then receive intents notifying you about discovered tags through the activity's `onNewIntent()` method:

```
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    ...
}
```

Moreover, you have to disable the foreground dispatch in your activity's `onPause()` method:

```
NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
```

Comment: The two techniques are not mutually exclusive. `enableForegroundDispatch()` only addresses the case when the application is in the foreground. If the application is in the background (yet still running), scanning a new matching NDEF tag will still create a new instance of the activity, unless you use something like `singleTask` to try to mitigate that.

Comment: @CommonsWare True! I didn't consider that case.