# Android & NFC - Reopen existing background activity

Tags: android, nfc

I've made an Android app that catch some NFC tags. All works fine when my app is on foreground.

But in the following case, I can't take my app work as expected :

1. Run my app -> Tags are correctly handled
2. Hide my app -> it goes to background
3. Use a NFC tag -> Android launch my app

In the third step, I want Android to set back to foreground my app and not to launch a second activity but I can't found the solution...

Any idea on this point ?
**Edit**

**I've solved my problem** doing the following:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

instead of

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

This way, Android always uses only one task for my activity and reuse my backgrounded activity in the third step described in my question.

Hope it will help some people.

Comment: Would this QA http://stackoverflow.com/q/23301903/2425802 qualify as a duplicate for you? If it does not: Please *do **not** edit* the answer in your question. Post it as an answer instead.